# Child thread cannot exit correctly

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I have a program with a main thread and two child threads, the main thread is the GUI thread. One child gets and detects the serial ports available in the current system, the other is for serial communication.

The problem here is that I want to exit the two sub-threads correctly and safely when closing the window.

Here's the code, I deleted some content that I think is not relevant:

---

### Main Thread

**wight.h:**

```
class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

signals:
    // to close the check serial thread
    void Stop_Serial_Monitor_Thread();
private slots:
    // serial port switch
    void On_Operate_Serial_Switch_Btn_Clicked();
    // update serial list
    void Update_Serial_List(QStringList serials);

    void On_Sel_Dir_Toolbtn_Clicked();

private:
    void Init_ComBoxs();
    void Operator_Serial_Switch();
    void Init_Card_Info_List();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;

    // serial port  comm thread
    Serial_Comm_Worker* m_serial_comm_worker;
    QThread m_serial_comm_thread;
    // update serial port port thread
    Check_Serial_Monitor_Thread* m_check_serial_thread;

};
```

**widget.cpp:**

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setWindowTitle("bootloader");

    Init_ComBoxs();
    Init_Card_Info_List();

    // create
    m_check_serial_thread = new Check_Serial_Monitor_Thread();

    m_serial_comm_worker = new Serial_Comm_Worker();
    m_serial_comm_worker->moveToThread(&m_serial_comm_thread);

    // update serial port list
    connect(m_check_serial_thread,
            &Check_Serial_Monitor_Thread::Have_Change_Serial,
            this,&Widget::Update_Serial_List,
            Qt::QueuedConnection);

    // destroy thread
    connect(&m_serial_comm_thread, &QThread::finished,
            m_serial_comm_worker, &QObject::deleteLater);
    connect(m_check_serial_thread,&QThread::finished,
            m_check_serial_thread,&QObject::deleteLater);

    connect(ui->operate_serial_switch_btn,&QPushButton::clicked,
                this,&Widget::On_Operate_Serial_Switch_Btn_Clicked);

    // to close the check serial port thread
    connect(this,&Widget::Stop_Serial_Monitor_Thread,
            m_check_serial_thread,&Check_Serial_Monitor_Thread::Stop_Cur_Thread,
            Qt::QueuedConnection);

    // child thread start 
    m_serial_comm_thread.start();
    m_check_serial_thread->start();


}

Widget::~Widget()
{

    emit Stop_Serial_Monitor_Thread();

    if(ui->operate_serial_switch_btn->text() == QString("关闭")){
        Operator_Serial_Switch();
    }

    m_check_serial_thread->quit();
    m_check_serial_thread->wait();

    m_serial_comm_thread.quit();
    m_serial_comm_thread.wait();

    delete ui;

}
```

---

### Check_Serial_Monitor_Thread

**Check_Serial_Monitor_Thread.h:**

```
class Check_Serial_Monitor_Thread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Check_Serial_Monitor_Thread(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    ~Check_Serial_Monitor_Thread();

    void run();

signals:
    void Have_Change_Serial(QStringList);

public slots:
    void Stop_Cur_Thread();

public:
    QStringList m_odd_serial_list;

    // running flag
    bool open_flag;

};
```

**Check_Serial_Monitor_Thread.cpp:**

```
#include "Check_Serial_Monitor_Thread.h"

Check_Serial_Monitor_Thread::Check_Serial_Monitor_Thread(QObject* parent)
{
    open_flag = true;
}

Check_Serial_Monitor_Thread::~Check_Serial_Monitor_Thread()
{

}

void Check_Serial_Monitor_Thread::run()
{
    m_odd_serial_list.clear();
    QStringList tmp_str_list;

    while(open_flag){// 不断检测是否有新的可用串口出现

        tmp_str_list.clear();
        foreach (const QSerialPortInfo &info, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()) {
            tmp_str_list += info.portName();
        }

        if(tmp_str_list != m_odd_serial_list){
            m_odd_serial_list = tmp_str_list;
            Custom_Tools::Print("Update available serial port!");
            emit Have_Change_Serial(tmp_str_list);
        }
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}

void Check_Serial_Monitor_Thread::Stop_Cur_Thread()
{
    Custom_Tools::Print("Quit Slot");
    open_flag = false;
}
```

there's another sub-thread created by `movetothread`, which is responsible for serial communication, but it has no errors so I'm excluding it.

The problematic thread is implemented by inheriting `QThread`，
its run function will continuously check the state of `open_flag`. If it is **true**, it will always check whether the current available serial port has been updated, and if so, it will send a signal. The corresponding slot method has been linked in `widget.cpp`.

### Problem

I send `Stop_Serial_Monitor_Thread()` in the destructor of the main thread; the corresponding slot method will change the `open_flag` to **false**.

What I want is to end the loop in the run function, use the finished signal, and then call the quit and below wait, making this thread safe to exit.

I know that I added `Qt::QueuedConnection` here to connect the signal and the slot, because it is the slot method of the signal connection sub-thread in the main thread. But after I added it, the program couldn't exit.

I know that `Qt::QueuedConnection` will put the event into the event queue of the corresponding thread, but the run function has been in an endless loop (the default initial `open_flag` is **true**), and in my rewritten implementation, it is not turned on event loop, so I added `exec()` at the beginning or end of run, or manually open the event loop, that is, add in while, `QCoreApplication::processEvents()`, it is useless, only when I remove the `Qt::QueuedConnection`, the program can exit normally.

Later, I found out that I send the main thread `emit Stop_Serial_Monitor_Thread();`.

The position of the signal has been changed and put in other functions, not in the destructor. I found that the slot function can be executed smoothly again, but this is not my purpose.

It confuses me now that I don't know what the problem is.

**System environment:**

- Windows 11
- Qt version : 5.9.0 MinGW 32bit

Comment: So much code for something which csan be easily done with a simple QTimer ... 
Since the Check_Serial_Monitor_Thread object lives in the main thread (as properly explained in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qthread.html#details) and you use a QueuedConnection it can't be executed since you don't return to the main threads eventloop.

Comment: From the brief review: QThread object is part of Widget object and that could be a problem. Either you do QThread wait https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#wait at Widget destructor or make that QThread object outside of Widget object.

Comment: chehrlic and AlexanderV,
thank for you reply.
I've changed some of these methods in the past few days, but I still find that there is a problem,
later,I think I have found the answer, because in the destructor of the main thread, the program executes too fast, the signal is sent out, and the program is closed before it has time to execute.
Maybe it's also because of the problem :)